# What are the available charting software for web / desktop (preferrably both) application

Tags: jquery, html, charts, fusioncharts

I am looking for various options for charting/graphing.

My requirements are

- this is for a business demo and hence needs to be really cool. And have all the bells/whistles like animations etc.
- It needs to support a large set of chart/graph types (line, bar, pie, polar etc)
- it should be highly configurable
- it is for a larger audience and put on a projector. Hence it should have features like ability to control the size of labels, legend, etc
- I prefer to go with something thats Jquery/Javascript/html5 based as these are latest technologies to stay and can suit tablets to big screens.

I need to know the pros and cons of various packages.

- I saw things like FusionCharts (flash based), but has a lot of features
- jqplot (jquery based)
- some silverlight based

Need to understand which one meets my requirements best and has all the features.

I am open to anything as long as it meets the above requirements.

Comment: While I'm not qualified to give you a full run-down of pros and cons for various packages, I've found http://d3js.org/ to be a pretty intense and flexible package to work with. You may just have your mind blown. There's lots of other SO questions on this topic so be sure to point out in your question what you have found.

Comment: FusionCharts is no longer Flash-based. They've jumped on the HTML5 / JavaScript bandwagon for a while now. Check out their gallery - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/ - the samples there are rendered in JavaScript by default.

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari, FusionCharts still have flash support. & you have to specify explicitly with `Fusioncharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');` to make your graphs as JS charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont agree with what @Hrishikesh Choudhari has said above.

FusionCharts Free renders charts in only in Flash. Where as the paid version XT renders the graphs in Flash & JS.

see **Note** section in this link: http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/

You need to specify your charts explicitly if you want to render them in JS as default. with `Fusioncharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');`. If you dont specify it then It will first look for flash if its not there( iPad) then it will render the chart in JS.
There are very minute, I should say insignificant, cosmetic changes in Flash & JS version.

You can likewise use [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) if you want free charts. Some of the Silverlight charts look promising too.

Comment: You're right in that sense - FusionCharts XT and FusionCharts Free are two distinct products. FusionCharts Free was open-sourced in 2009, and is not under development. FusionCharts XT is the main flagship product, with JavaScript capabilities. And as you said, the visual differences between Flash and JavaScript charts are insignificant. However, the FusionCharts API remains the same for both versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

It has a very good documentation, with many chart types and lots of configurable options.

It's for web, built using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts is no longer Flash-based.

They've jumped on the HTML5 / JavaScript bandwagon for a while now.

Check out their gallery - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/ - the samples there are rendered in JavaScript by default.

Comment: FusionCharts Free renders charts only in Flash. The XT version has in Javascript & Flash. Please correct your answer.

Comment: @uDaY OP didn't specify FusionCharts Free.. See my comment for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We use ChartDirector here. It works with ASP.Net, Java, ASP Classic etc..

Its pretty cool for the most part except they don't seem to want to answer any support questions. Even if you've paid for it... like we did.

I'm really telling you this because I hope they somehow see this and answer my damned questions.

Answer (score 0):

We used http://nvd3.org for our automatic chart generation tool at http://www.datacopia.com.  It has a very straightforward API and the documentation/sample code is fairly complete.